# lsqnonlin optimization error in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization

I face a problem solving an optimization problem in Matlab. I have an objective function, that I need to minimize.

I run this code in Matlab using the *lsqnonlin* function:

```
[objective] = @(E) objective(E);
options = optimoptions(@lsqnonlin,'Algorithm','trust-region-reflective','MaxFunEvals',2000);

lowb = [0.00001 0.00001 0.00001]; % lower bounds
uppb = [30 30 30]; % upper bounds

E0 = [0.00001 0.00001 0.00001]; %initial guess

problem = createOptimProblem('lsqnonlin', 'objective', objective, 'x0', E0, 'lb', lowb, 'ub', uppb, 'options', options);

ms = MultiStart;
matlabpool open
ms.UseParallel = 'always';
startpoints = RandomStartPointSet('NumStartPoints',100);
[E, fval, exitflag, output, solutions] = run(ms, problem, startpoints); 

matlabpool close
```

I get this error finally and I cannot continue:
***The Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm does not handle bound constraints and the
trust-region-reflective algorithm requires at least as many equations as variables; aborting.***

Could you please tell me what is going wrong?Those are my first attempts in optimization toolbox in Matlab, so I don't know many things.

Comment: use less start points in `RandomStartPointSet` and not use `upper/lower` bounds, i think this is the source of the error you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lsqnonlin` function allows you to choose between `'levenberg-marquardt'` and `'trust-region-reflective'`. You have chosen `'trust-region-reflective'`, but the error message is misleading in that it reports the different requirements for each option. The documentation for `lsqnonlin` [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqnonlin.html#f265106) explains this more clearly.

In your case, this error is caused by the fact that your objective function `E` returns less values (the 'equations' referred to in the error message) than there are variables (3). Is the output of `E` a scalar or a 2-vector? You could avoid this error by changing the solver to `'levenberg-marquardt'`, but then you would have to abandon the bound constraints.

Optimization is complicated and very sensitive to the specific problem at hand. MathWorks provides a fairly comprehensive guide for [choosing a solver](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/choosing-a-solver.html). In your case, you need to characterize your objective function (which you have neglected to post). Is it:

1. Linear?
2. Quadratic?
3. Least Squares? (*This is what your choice of `lsqnonlin` suggests, but I suspect your objective function `E` is a scalar function)*
4. Smooth nonlinear?
5. Nonsmooth?

Combined with your bound constraints, the type of objective function will present the choices available in the table at the [choosing a solver](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/choosing-a-solver.html) page. At that point, be sure to read the documentation for the optimization function you have selected in order to get the best results.